# MeshLab: fill cracks in mesh

Tags: graphics, geometry, meshlab

I'm having trouble finding a way to solve this specific problem using MeshLab.

[image: Mesh's craks]

As you can see in the figure, the mesh with which I'm working presents some cracks in certain areas, and I would like to try to close them. The "close holes" option does not seem to work because, being technically cracks and not holes, it seems not to be able to weld them.

I managed to get a good result using the "Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction" option, but using this operation (rebuilding the whole mesh topology), I would lose all the information about the mesh's UVs (and I can not afford to lose them).

I would need some advice to find the best method to weld these cracks, which does not change the vertices that are not along them, adding only the geometry needed to close the mesh (or, ideally, to make a weld using the existing edges along the edge).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The close holes option should be able to handle this. Did you try changing the max size for that filter to a much larger number? Do filters >> selection >> select border and put the number of selected faces as the max size into that filter

Comment: @A.Comer Sorry for the late reply, you were right, in the end I solved the problem by simply playing around with the parameters of the "close holes" tool. It's a pity that your comment is not a "real answer" (in stackoverflow sense), otherwise I would mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by [A.Comer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7564109/a-comer) in a comment to the main question, I was able to get the desired result simply by playing a bit with the parameters of the "close holes" tool.

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a copy of the comment:

> The close holes option should be able to handle this. Did you try changing the max size for that filter to a much larger number? Do filters >> selection >> select border and put the number of selected faces as the max size into that filter – A.Comer